# GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH on the command line?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I understand that I can use custom models using the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:

```
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=path/to/models
```

Is there a way to do this from the command line?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22089/gazebo_model_path-on-the-command-line?/) by [clydemcqueen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3875/clydemcqueen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-03-13**:
Not sure I understand the question, you can use the command you mentioned on the command line, right?

**Comment by [clydemcqueen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3875/clydemcqueen/) on 2019-04-17**:
Thanks for the response, @chapulina. My question wasn't well formed. I was looking to avoid dependency on environment variables... and was looking for an option like "gazebo -m path/to/models".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks for the clarification. There's no command-line argument to set model/plugin/resource paths, but it could be an interesting addition.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1